# Lotus Notes - open a file from Action Button

Tags: file, lotus-notes

Is there any chance to open a file / document ( .pdf / .txt ) that is located in (for example ) the C drive:  from an action button?

I read about Shell function in LotusScript, in which you must specify the path.

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open a file like .pdf or .txt and this extension is connected in Windows with a program to open with then you need only to specify the filepath of your file.

This would be the formula:

```
@Command([Execute]; "C:\\temp\\myFile.pdf")
```

and this the LotusScript code:

```
Dim result As Integer
result = Shell("C:\temp\myFile.pdf", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! What if it is a .dsx extension , which may be launch only from cmd? Is it possible to open-it from Lotus?

Comment: It depends on installed applications in your Windows system. You have to test it: just double click on file in Windows Explorer. If file gets opened then it should work from Notes too.

Comment: Btw, dear @Knut Herrmann: is it possible to open a pdf which is on a web address? Let say: www.ibm.com/test1.pdf ?

Comment: @URLOpen("http://www.ibm.com/test1.pdf");  There are some other options, which you can learn about here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_URLOPEN.html